# How to find the missing next character in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of characters like this:

```
['a','b','c','d','f']
['O','Q','R','S']
```

If we see that, there is one letter is missing from each of the arrays. First one has `e` missing and the second one has `P` missing. Care to be taken for the case of the character as well. So, if I have a huge Object which has all the letters in order, and check them for the next ones, and compare?

I am totally confused on what approach to follow! This is what I have got till now:

```
var chars = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"+"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toUpperCase()).split("");
```

So this gives me with:

```
["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m",
 "n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
 "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M",
 "N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
```

Which is awesome. Now my question is, how do I like check for the missing character in the range? Some kind of forward lookup?

I tried something like this:

- Find the `indexOf` starting value in the source array.
- Compare it with each of them.
- If the comparison failed, return the one from the original array?

Comment: Forward lookup? Negative look ahead?

Comment: The reasoning seems sound given the problem description.  It seems as though you've answered your own question, to be honest (in the steps you list).

Comment: @PraveenKumar Not as in RegExp, but similar. Not sure what to put it as.

Comment: @Nicholas Yea, but I am not sure how I should be looping it.

Comment: @CodeWarsHelp I wouldn't use the HUUUUGE array or object that you have... `:)`

Comment: Convert chars to a char array and utilize "intersection" from a library like lodash?

Comment: Forward Look-Ahead or Negative Look-Ahead: Well, my solution would be some kind of that. So, if you see this, what I would do is, I'll keep track of them using the Character's Code, instead of the array.

Comment: @HaukurKristinsson Already it's a char array right? And yeah, I can't use libraries... `:(` This is a CodeWars stuff, which doesn't allow me to use libraries or anything. Have to do it manually.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Character Code instead of Array? Do you wish to explain?

Comment: @CodeWarsHelp Writing answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that a much better way is to check for each element in your array if the next element is the next char:

```js
function checkMissingChar(ar) {
  for (var i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
    if (ar[i].charCodeAt(0) == ar[i-1].charCodeAt(0)+1) {
      // console.log('all good');
    } else {
      return String.fromCharCode(ar[i-1].charCodeAt(0)+1);
    }
  }
  return true;
}

var a = ['a','b','c','d','f']
var b = ['O','Q','R','S']

console.log(checkMissingChar(a));
console.log(checkMissingChar(b));
```

> Not that I start to check the array with the second item because I compare it to the item before (the first in the Array).

Comment: Yup... This is much simpler as well.

Comment: Okay, you win this time! Ha ha.

Comment: Dude, I don't understand this part: `return String.fromCharCode(ar[i-1].charCodeAt(0)+1);` Can't this be just written as `return ar[i];`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar sorry for the late response. The missing char is not at the array, so you can't do `return ar[i];` You need to take the prev char, get the code from it, add 1 to the code and convert back to char.

Answer (score 1):

Forward Look-Ahead or Negative Look-Ahead: Well, my solution would be some kind of that. So, if you see this, what I would do is, I'll keep track of them using the Character's Code using [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt), instead of the array.

```js
function findMissingLetter(array) {
  var ords = array.map(function (v) {
    return v.charCodeAt(0);
  });
  var prevOrd = "p";
  for (var i = 0; i < ords.length; i++) {
    if (prevOrd == "p") {
      prevOrd = ords[i];
      continue;
    }
    if (prevOrd + 1 != ords[i]) {
      return String.fromCharCode(ords[i] - 1);
    }
    prevOrd = ords[i];
  }
}

console.log(findMissingLetter(['a','b','c','d','f']));
console.log(findMissingLetter(['O','Q','R','S']));
```

Since I come from a PHP background, I use some PHP related terms like ordinal, etc. In PHP, you can get the charCode using the [`ord()`](http://php.net/manual/function.ord.php).

As Dekel's answer is better than mine, I'll try to propose somewhat more better answer:

```js
function findMissingLetter (ar) {
  for (var i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
    if (ar[i].charCodeAt(0) != ar[i-1].charCodeAt(0)+1) {
      return String.fromCharCode(ar[i-1].charCodeAt(0)+1);
    }
  }
  return true;
}

var a = ['a','b','c','d','f']
var b = ['O','Q','R','S']

console.log(findMissingLetter(a));
console.log(findMissingLetter(b));
```

Shorter and Sweet.

Comment: I'm really not sure why you need the mapping there and the `prevOrd = "p"`. You can check my answer, I think it's much simpler.

Comment: @Dekel Should I delete my answer? Yours is better than mine.

Comment: Well, basically it's almost the same as mine :) if you think that your answer gives something that I didn't cover - it should be available for people to learn.

Comment: And if mine is better I would appreciate a vote :) haha

Comment: Can you help me in converting this into PHP then? Let's try that?

Comment: @CodeWarsHelp Okay, writing... You gonna ask a new question then?

Comment: @CodeWarsHelp Struggling. LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Wait for another 45 mins, you have a lot time to complete it.