# Find the missing next character in the array

Tags: php, arrays

Similar to the [How to find the missing next character in the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496948). I need to implement the same in PHP. I have this in JavaScript now:

```js
function findMissingLetter (ar) {
  for (var i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
    if (ar[i].charCodeAt(0) != ar[i-1].charCodeAt(0)+1) {
      return String.fromCharCode(ar[i-1].charCodeAt(0)+1);
    }
  }
  return true;
}

var a = ['a','b','c','d','f']
var b = ['O','Q','R','S']

console.log(findMissingLetter(a));
console.log(findMissingLetter(b));
```

I want to convert this into PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = ["a","b","c","d","f"];
$res = range(current($arr), end($arr));
$missing = array_diff($res, $arr);
echo end($missing);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Quick things... You need to replace:

- `.charCodeAt(0)` with [`ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) (Return ASCII value of character).
- All the variables should be replaced with `$` in the front.
- `String.fromCharCode()` should be replaced as [`chr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) (Return a specific character from ASCII value).
- `.length` is replaced as `count()`.

The final code is:

```
<?php
  function findMissingLetter ($array) {
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
      if (ord($array[$i]) != ord($array[$i - 1]) + 1) {
        return chr(ord($array[$i - 1]) + 1);
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  echo findMissingLetter(['a', 'b', 'd']); // c
?>
```

This should work! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is always letters, you can just use PHP's handy letter incrementation as part of your iterative checks.  Short circuit the loop as soon as an unexpected value is encountered.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6TfYf))

```
$arr = ["a","b","c","d","f"];

$last = null;
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    if ($last !== null) {
        if (++$last !== $v) {
            echo $last;
            break;
        }
    }
    $last = $v;
}
```